# Modify element [0][0] in a Python 2D list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [append to a sublist appends to every sublist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190513/append-to-a-sublist-appends-to-every-sublist)

The 2D list is initialized as `grid=[[False]*N] *N`

print grid produces:

```
[[False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False], [False, False, False, False]]
```

Now I want the element in row 1 and column 1 to be true. I only want the element in row 1 and column 1 to be true. Other elements must be false.

`grid[0][0]=True`

After I set grid[0][0] to true, print grid produces:

`[[True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False]]`

But the first element of every row is now True, but I only want the first element of the first row to be true.

Please help. I'm new to Python.

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: @Abhijit: Which is itself a duplicate of 1000 earlier SO questions. I wonder what percentage of Python questions on SO are the same 10 basic things over and over?

Comment: @abarnert: I believe we should put one of this 1000 earlier SO questions in the Python FAQ

Comment: @Abhijit: I guess. But it's already in the official Python tutorial, and the reference documentation, and I don't think I've ever seen a tutorial that explains that you can use `*` on `list` without immediately explaining the shallow-copy pitfall, so… you think it would do much good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

multiplying a single reference data type would simply create multiple references of the same type.
What it means is that [True]*N is actually N times the same instance of the element [True]

Thus changing one would inadvertently change the others

As you can see in the following example,

```
>>> grid = [[True]]*10
>>> grid = [True]*10
>>> [id(e) for e in grid]
[505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788, 505379788]
```

It shows all the elements are actually the same instance.

But because here as the element is not a mutable Type, changing won't be an issue here as, changing one of the element would simply assign a new instance.

Problem happens with a mutable type

```
>>> [id(e) for e in grid]
[66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744]
>>> grid[0][0]=False
>>> [id(e) for e in grid]
[66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744, 66523744]
>>> grid
[[False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False], [False]]
```

To get over it, you need to understand which are mutable types and refrain from duplicating it but instead create new multiple instances of the same mutable types

So here as a list is a mutable type, you need to create multiple instances, possibly through list comprehension

```
[[False]*N for _ in range(N)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Much like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14190513/1907098), you're lists are in fact pointing to the same list. Instead, define your list as:

```
[[False] * N for i in xrange(N)]
```

Or in Python 3:

```
[[False] * N for i in range(N)]
```

Then modifying one element will modify **only** that element.

Note the Python 3 `range` function also works in Python 2 - however in Python 2 the `range` function returns a list, as opposed to a `range` object in Python 3, and the `xrange` object of Python 2, both of which are iterators.

Comment: You can do `[False]*N` - this "problem" only happens with mutable objects.

Comment: @Tim of course, how could I forget? Edited to reflect that.

Comment: `Note the Python 3 version is also backwards compatible, and works in Python 2.`, not sure why you mentioned this for this Question, but this is not entirely correct

Comment: @Abhijit the `range` function exists in Python 2... it just returns a list instead of an `xrange` object

Comment: @Volatility: True for range, but the statement in generic sense is incorrect. You can just highlight that you are referring to `range` and `xrange` and the difference in its usage in Python 2 Vs Python 3