# Appending to element in array

Tags: python, list, 3d, append

I'm new to python, and I'm having trouble with certain aspects of the language. Right now I'm trying to create a 3 dimensional table that can hold certain values.

table[x][y][z]

X and Y are both initialized to have the same number of elements, and z is initialized to be an empty list like so

```
table = [[[]]*length]*length
```

so that a table of length 3 would look like-

[[[],[],[]] , [[],[],[]] , [[],[],[]]]

At certain values of x, y I would like to be able to append a singular z list like this

```
table[0][2].append('S')
```

would cause the table to look like

[[[],[],['S']] , [[],[],[]] , [[],[],[]]]

but it's coming out like this

[[['S'],['S'],['S']] , [['S'],['S'],['S']] , [['S'],['S'],['S']]]

so that every z list is appended. Why is this happening and how can i fix it. I can work around this inefficiently but I don't want to.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190513/append-to-a-sublist-appends-to-every-sublist/14190543#14190543

Answer (score 1):

The statement

`table = [[[]]*length]*length`

Just gives you references to the same 2 innermost lists over and over again.

Comment: Sorry I'm terribly ill versed in python terminology. Are you saying that the same inner most list [] is being used for each value of x and y? And if so do you have any recommendations for how I would implement different inner most lists? a for loop where the inner loop is table[x][y] = []?

Comment: sorted thanks again though!